# Как избежать повторного вызова HighloadBlockTable::compileEntity?

Tags: битрикс

Создал две HL-таблицы и думал, что связал их  (один-ко-многим) свойством "Привязка к элементам highload-блока". Вопреки ожиданиям поле оказалось `string`. Содержит `id`:

```
'UF_PROPERTY' => string(1) "1" // id
```

Как избежать повторного вызова `HighloadBlockTable::compileEntity`, чтобы сделать выборку свойства из другой таблицы одним запросом? То есть вместо строки с `id` нужно получить сразу элементы из связанной таблицы.

```
use Bitrix\Highloadblock;

$entity = Highloadblock\HighloadBlockTable::compileEntity('Inversed');
$dataClass = $entity->getDataClass();

$result = $dataClass::getList();

while ($dataArray = $result->fetch()) {
  $idArray[] = $dataArray['UF_PROPERTY']['ID'];
}

$entity = Highloadblock\HighloadBlockTable::compileEntity('Mapped');
$dataClass = $entity->getDataClass();

$result = $dataClass::getList([,
  'filter' => ['ID' => $idArray]
]);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать ORM bitrix для работы с HL
[Пример](http://sirbiladze.ru/2017/05/28/highloadblock-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C-orm/)

И уже в выборках можно задать связывание

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)